# Check if NavMeshAgent can reach position with dynamic obstacles

Tags: unity, 2d, ai, navmesh

I am currently checking if a position in the NavMesh is reachable. It is reachable without the NavMesh obstacles. But the moment I add it, NavMesh's `CalculatePath()` continues to return true. Note that I do have those obstacles to have carving set to true. How do I solve this problem?

Reference:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1184356/how-to-know-if-a-navigationmeshagent-is-impossible.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by doing the ff:

```
public bool CanReachPosition(Vector2 position)
{
      NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();
      agent.CalculatePath(position, path);
      return path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete;
}
```

After getting the path, we need to check if the path is `NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete` or if the path is getting to the destination. The path will be `.PathPartial` if the path is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

There is a NavMeshObstacle for dynamic obstacles. As you already, pointed out you are using them with Carving set to true (so they make a whole in navmesh, that agents should avoid - described in [docs, see "carving"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NavMeshObstacle.html)). But checking boolean result of NavMeshAgent.CalculatePath(target, path) is not enough as it is about whether path is found or not. We need to check if path is full (not partial) through path.status after the call, e.g.:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;
    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();
        agent.CalculatePath(target.position, path);
        if (path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Example based on [docs on CalculatePath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.CalculatePath.html). For full list of path statuses, see [AI.NavMeshPathStatus](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshPathStatus.html).

Comment: Could you provide more detail to explain how to use this to solve the problem OP is describing? Pointing out there is a thing is below the minimum of what an answer should contain.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Now I understand that searching through many answers and providing solutions in-between I answered in wrong question. But I edited, so it gives details on both the problem described here and the answer

Comment: Thanks for stopping by to update it! I noticed the if statement is blank. In case that's intentional I put a `// ...` there to indicate a sort of "put something here"; you may want to amend if there's lines missing by accident or if you want to provide more specific guidance.